# Convert time xx:xxam or xx:xxpm to ISOString

Tags: javascript, date, time, momentjs

Is there a know way to convert `10:12am` and/or `12:10pm` to `ISOString` format?

So far, I was trying to detect if the the time is an `am` or `pm` then remove the last 2 chars. After that im just appending new date string like :

```
export function timeAMPMToISO(time) {
    var newTime = time.slice(0, -2)
    var isAmPm = time.substr(-2)
    var h = parseInt(newTime.split(':')[0])
    var m = newTime.split(':')[1]
    var date = new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 11);
    if(isAmPm === 'pm'){
        if(h === 12){
            h = h
        }else{
            h += 12
        }
    }
    h = (isAmPm === 'am' && h === 12) ? '00' : h;
    return `${ date }${ h }:${ m }:00.000Z`;
}
```

I have a feeling that this is not normal.

Is there an existing library for this? `MomentJs` perhaps? If so, how?

Thanks.

Comment: There are a [*huge number of duplicates*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+convert+to+24+hour+time), please do some minimal searching for answers before posting a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse your input using [`moment (String, String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) and then use [`toISOString()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/).

Your code can be like the following:

```
moment('10:12am', 'hh:mma').toISOString()
```

The `hh` token matches 1-12 hours, `mm` matches 0-59 minutes and `a` matches am/pm

Comment: This is what I am looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Did you down vote my question? HAHA

Comment: No, I was not the downvoter, neither I flagged it as duplicate. :)

Comment: Ok thanks! That's fine :D